Microsoft Defender Advance Hunting with CloudAppEvents for Forensic data created with Purview
Goal: To be able use endpoint RunHuntingQuery and get alert / incident forensic data (like match count, policy name etc) for recent alerts created by Purview policies.
Problem: The alerts and incidents endpoints in graph API do not provide forensic data in the response. However, when the alert is created and you view it in Microsoft Defender portal, there is an option to "Go Hunt"
Microsoft Defender Alerts Go hunt
Also notice that on this alert page you can see the Forensic data (matched against policy and matched data)
When you click on User DLP violations for the last 30 days, it takes you Advance hunting and populates a query which uses the CloudAppEvents
let user = ('test1@****.onmicrosoft.com'); 
CloudAppEvents    
| where ActionType has "DLPRuleMatch" or ActionType has "DLPRuleUndo" or RawEventData.PolicyMatchInfo.PolicyId <> ""
| where tolower(user) == tolower(RawEventData.UserId)
| extend PolicyName_ = tostring(parse_json(tostring(RawEventData.
.
.


However, when i run this query, the Results are blank. Even if i run a query with just CloudAppEvents as the query i get blank results. But if i run a query with AlertEvidence, i get results.
So it seems like either some integration needs to be done in Microsoft Defender with Cloud App connector or i am missing some permission. But this is where i am stuck as i cannot find any documentation on how to get it to work.
Expectation: be able to see Forensic information for an alert.
Troubleshooting so far :
Validated in Defender portal Settings - Cloud apps Microsoft 365 connector is added (however it only has Azure AD Users and Groups component enabled. Not sure if i need Office 365 components ?
Office 365 connector

I had some progress on this.
if i just run
CloudAppEvents
| where ActivityType == "Securityevent"
i get results, i see the policy and other details, however under RawEventData the value for SensitiveInfoDetectionIsIncluded is false and so the matched content does not show.
I need to do something for DLP Schema to enable this value, but not sure. I will update this thread once i have an answer
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/office-365-management-activity-api-schema#dlp-schema
